# Mapping a function each list in a list of lists

Tags: python

I've been given a homework task that asks me to find in a list of data the greatest continuous increase. i.e [1,2,3,4,5,3,1,2,3] the greatest static increase here is 4.

I've written a function that takes a single list and spits out a list of sublists like this.

```py
def group_data(lst): 
    sublist= [[lst[0]]] 

    for i in range(1, len(lst)): 
        if  lst[i-1] < lst[i]: 
            sublist[-1].append(lst[i]) 

        else: 
            sublist.append([lst[i]]) 
    return(sublist)
```

Which does what it's supposed to

```
group_data([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,5,4,7,8])
Out[3]: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 5], [4, 7, 8]]
```

And I now want to subtract the last element of each individual list from the first to find their differences. But I'm having difficulty figuring out how to map the function to each list rather than each element of the list. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using map function where arr is your grouped list

```py
list(map(lambda x: x[-1]-x[0], arr ))
```

Answer (score 0):

For this problem I think `itertools.groupby` would be a good choice. Since your final goal is to find the difference of longest consecutive numbers:

```
from itertools import groupby
max_l = max([len(list(g)) - 1 for k, g in groupby(enumerate([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,5,4,7,8]), key=lambda x: x[0] - x[1])])
print(max_l)
#it will print 9
```

Explanation:
First groupby the numbers with the difference between index and number value. For example `[0, 1, 2, 4]` will create `[0, 0, 0, 1]` as the index of `0` is `0`, so `0-0=0`, for the second one `1-1=0`. Then take the maximum length of the grouped list. Since you want difference, I used `len(list(g)) - 1`